# How do I find a cell that contains several values?

Tags: vba, find

I have tried the Find function but it only searches for a single value... i need to search for the cell that contains several values within the same cell. 
i.e.. a cell containing "new" "car" "red"

Edit 1, This is what I have for now... Thank you so much for the comments and the help. It is working for now, I would appreciate further optimizing.

```
Private Sub Run_Click()
Dim Val As Variant, v5 As Range, Count As Long, Temp1 As String, Temp2 As String, Temp3 As String
Dim pos1, pos2, pos3 As Integer
Dim Centinel1, Centinel2 As Boolean
Centinel1 = True
While Centinel1 = True
    i = 2
    Val = Cells(i, 1).Value
    If Val <> "" Then
        Count = 0

        ' Gather values from source

        v1 = Cells(i, 1).Value
        v2 = Cells(i, 2).Value
        v3 = Left(Cells(i, 3).Value, 3)
        v4 = Mid(Cells(i, 3).Value, InStrRev(Cells(i, 3).Value, "-") - 2, 2)

        Centinel2 = True
        Temp1 = "$B$2"

        While Centinel2 = True
                Set v5 = Sheets("RWI").Range("B1:B1000").Find(What:=v1, After:=Range(Temp1))
                pos1 = InStr(v5, v2)
                pos2 = InStr(v5, v3)
                pos3 = InStr(v5, v4)

                Temp2 = v5.Address

                GetTail1 = Mid(Temp1, InStrRev(Temp1, "$") + 1)
                GetTail2 = Mid(Temp2, InStrRev(Temp2, "$") + 1)

                'Check if all matches are within "Find"

                If pos1 > 1 And pos2 > 1 And pos3 > 1 Then

                    MsgBox v5 & "  " & Sheets("RWI").Range(v5.Address).Offset(, -1)
                    Centinel2 = False

                ElseIf Temp1 > Temp2 Then

                    MsgBox "Description not found."
                    Centinel2 = False

                Else

                    Temp1 = v5.Address

                End If

        Wend

        i = i + 1

        Centinel1 = False
    Else
        Centinel1 = False
    End If
Wend
```

End Sub

Edit 3: This is what my code looks like now...

```
Private Sub Run_Click()

Dim Val As Variant, v5 As Range, Count As Long, i As Long
Dim GetTail1, GetTail2 As Long
Dim Cellsave, Temp1, Temp2, Temp3, v1, v2, v3, v4, R, Sheet, v0, v22 As String
Dim pos1, pos2, pos3 As Integer
Dim Centinel1, Centinel2, Centinel3 As Boolean

If RWbutton.Value = True Then
    R = "RW-"
    Sheet = "RW Overflow Sheet"
ElseIf RWIbutton.Value = True Then
    R = "RWI-"
    Sheet = "RWI Overflow Sheet"
End If

Centinel1 = True
i = 2

If Me.ResultsCol.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please input valid column letter to save results at"
Else
    While Centinel1 = True
        Val = Sheets(Sheet).Cells(i, 1).Value
        If Val <> "" Then
            Count = 0

            Centinel3 = False

            ' Gather values from source
            v0 = R
            v1 = "-" & Sheets(Sheet).Cells(i, 1).Value & "-"

            ' Check if v2 has - or (A or B)
            If Sheets(Sheet).Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*-*" And (Sheets(Sheet).Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*A*" Or Sheets(Sheet).Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*B*") Then
                v2 = Left(Sheets(Sheet).Cells(i, 2).Value, Application.Find("-", Sheets(Sheet).Cells(i, 2).Value) - 1) & "-"
                v22 = Right(Sheets(Sheet).Cells(i, 2).Value, 1)
                Centinel3 = True
            ElseIf Sheets(Sheet).Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*-*" Then
                v2 = "-" & Right(Sheets(Sheet).Cells(i, 2).Value, (Len(Sheets(Sheet).Cells(i, 2).Value) - InStrRev(Sheets(Sheet).Cells(i, 2).Value, "-")))
            Else
                v2 = Sheets(Sheet).Cells(i, 2).Value & "-"
            End If

            v3 = Left(Sheets(Sheet).Cells(i, 3).Value, 3)
            v4 = Right(Sheets(Sheet).Cells(i, 3).Value, (Len(Sheets(Sheet).Cells(i, 3).Value) - InStrRev(Sheets(Sheet).Cells(i, 3).Value, "/")))

            Cellsave = Me.ResultsCol.Value & i
            Centinel2 = True
            Temp1 = "$B$1"

            While Centinel2 = True
                    Set v5 = Sheets("fnd_gfm").Range("B1:B1000").Find(What:=v0, After:=Range(Temp1))


                    If (Not v5 Is Nothing) Then
                        pos1 = InStr(v5, v1)
                        pos2 = InStr(v5, v2)
                        pos3 = InStr(v5, v3)
                        pos4 = InStr(v5, v4)

                        Temp2 = v5.Address


                        GetTail1 = Mid(Temp1, InStrRev(Temp1, "$") + 1)
                        GetTail2 = Mid(Temp2, InStrRev(Temp2, "$") + 1)

                        'Check if all matches are within "Find"
                        If pos1 > 1 And pos2 > 1 And pos3 > 1 And pos4 > 1 Then

                                'Check if Part Number has A or B in it
                                If Centinel3 = False Then
                                    Sheets(Sheet).Range(Cellsave).Value = Sheets("fnd_gfm").Range(v5.Address).Offset(, -1)
                                    Centinel2 = False

                                ElseIf Centinel3 = True Then
                                    Sheets(Sheet).Range(Cellsave).Value = Left(Sheets("fnd_gfm").Range(v5.Address).Offset(, -1).Value, (Len(Sheets("fnd_gfm").Range(v5.Address).Offset(, -1).Value) - 1)) & v22
                                    Centinel2 = False
                                    Centinel3 = False

                                End If

                            ElseIf GetTail1 > GetTail2 Then

                                'Check when Find does not find the value
                                Sheets(Sheet).Range(Cellsave).Value = "Not found."
                                Centinel2 = False


                            Else

                                Temp1 = v5.Address

                        End If

                    Else

                        Sheets(Sheet).Range(Cellsave).Value = "Not found."
                        Centinel2 = False

                    End If

            Wend

            i = i + 1

        Else
            Centinel1 = False
            MsgBox "Process Finished"
        End If
    Wend
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Try a loop that checks cells individually. If you find specific problems then post your code and we will be happy to help you fix it and improve it.

Comment: Like @A.S.H says, you will need to loop, but it will **probably** be best to loop using a `Find` for **one** of the terms and then, within that loop, test the matches of the `Find` to see if the found cells match the other terms too.  (A lot depends though on your data structure and volume.)

Comment: Will do, once I get to it tomorrow. Thank you so much!

Comment: @FabianGutierrez did my solution work? If so, I'd appreciate a green check! Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***UPDATED*** The code has been enhanced to be a little more user-friendly. It uses an array to store text fields via an input box so the number of search items is numerous.

```
      Sub FindLots()
      Dim TextArray() As String, Targetcell As Range
      Dim Answer As String, StartingAddress As String
      Dim AllSearchText As String, QuestionHeader As String
      Dim I As Long, t As Long, NumericAnswer As Long
      Dim NoMemberFound As Boolean
      
StartQuestion:
        If I = 0 Then
            QuestionHeader = "Enter Your Search Text"
        Else
            QuestionHeader = "Enter Your Search... part " & I + 1 & " !"
        
        End If
    
        Answer = InputBox("Add a field to search for and hit ""OK."" You will get a chance to enter search fields.", QuestionHeader, "Enter Text")
      
        If Answer = "" Then
          NumericAnswer = MsgBox("You didn't enter anything. Click ""Yes"" to try again. ""No"" to start search or ""Cancel"" to... cancel.", vbYesNoCancel, "Oh False!")
        
            If NumericAnswer = vbYes Then
                GoTo StartQuestion
            ElseIf NumericAnswer = vbCancel Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Else
        
            ReDim Preserve TextArray(I)
            TextArray(I) = Answer
            AllSearchText = AllSearchText & "," & Answer
            
            NumericAnswer = MsgBox("Would you like to add an additional members to search of """ & AllSearchText & """? Click no to continue search.", vbQuestion + vbYesNoCancel)
                If NumericAnswer = vbYes Then
                    I = I + 1
                    GoTo StartQuestion
                ElseIf NumericAnswer = vbCancel Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If
        End If
    
        On Error Resume Next
        If TextArray(0) = "" Then
            MsgBox "No Search text entered", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    
    
    Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = ActiveSheet 'or whatever sheet you want to search
    
    Set Targetcell = WS.Cells.Find(TextArray(0), WS.Cells(1, 1))
    
    If Targetcell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "coulnd't even find " & TextArray(0), vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf I = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Found your cell at " & Targetcell.Address
        Targetcell.Select
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    StartingAddress = Targetcell.Address
    
    Do
    NoMemberFound = False
    For t = 1 To I
    
    If Targetcell.Cells.Find(TextArray(t)) Is Nothing Then
        NoMemberFound = True
        Exit For
    End If
    Next t
    
    If NoMemberFound = False Then
        MsgBox "Found your cell at " & Targetcell.Address, , "Yea!"
        Targetcell.Select
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set Targetcell = WS.Cells.Find(TextArray(0), Targetcell)
    
    Loop Until Targetcell.Address = StartingAddress
    
    MsgBox "Unable to find cells with your criteria of " & Right(AllSearchText, Len(AllSearchText) - 1), vbInformation, "Is that bad?"
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Four years later... this was my first `accepted` answer on SO (OUCH -- Code Cringe!). I was such a try-hard.